Uncaught runtime errors: Network Error AxiosError
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:476728:14)
    at Axios.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:477169:41)
    at async http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2232:11

I am making Study Notion: an Ed-Tech platform.
when i do npm run dev i dont this error but when i do npm start ( that is start my frontend only) that is when this error occurs. I am not able to host my website because of this error.
I tried updating my axios version but still its not working. Please help.
This is my Review-Slider component
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
    import ReactStars from "react-rating-stars-component"
    // Import Swiper React components
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react"
    
    // Import Swiper styles
    import "swiper/css"
    import "swiper/css/free-mode"
    import "swiper/css/pagination"
    import "../../App.css"
    // Icons
    import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa"
    // Import required modules
    import { Autoplay, FreeMode, Pagination } from "swiper/modules";
    
    // Get apiFunction and the endpoint
    import { apiConnector } from "../../services/apiConnector"
    import { ratingsEndpoints } from "../../services/apis"
    
    function ReviewSlider() {
      const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([])
      const truncateWords = 15
    
      useEffect(() => {
        ;(async () => {
          const { data } = await apiConnector(
            "GET",
            ratingsEndpoints.REVIEWS_DETAILS_API
          )
          if (data?.success) {
            setReviews(data?.data)
          }
        })()
      }, [])
    
      // console.log(reviews)
    
      return (
        <div className="text-white">
          <div className="my-[50px] h-[184px] max-w-maxContentTab lg:max-w-maxContent">
            <Swiper
              slidesPerView={4}
              spaceBetween={25}
              loop={true}
              freeMode={true}
              autoplay={{
                delay: 2500,
                disableOnInteraction: false,
              }}
              modules={[FreeMode, Pagination, Autoplay]}
              className="w-full "
            >
              {reviews.map((review, i) => {
                return (
                  <SwiperSlide key={i}>
                    <div className="flex flex-col gap-3 bg-richblack-800 p-3 text-[14px] text-richblack-25">
                      <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
                        <img
                          src={
                            review?.user?.image
                              ? review?.user?.image
                              : `https://api.dicebear.com/5.x/initials/svg?seed=${review?.user?.firstName} ${review?.user?.lastName}`
                          }
                          alt=""
                          className="h-9 w-9 rounded-full object-cover"
                        />
                        <div className="flex flex-col">
                          <h1 className="font-semibold text-richblack-5">{`${review?.user?.firstName} ${review?.user?.lastName}`}</h1>
                          <h2 className="text-[12px] font-medium text-richblack-500">
                            {review?.course?.courseName}
                          </h2>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <p className="font-medium text-richblack-25">
                        {review?.review.split(" ").length > truncateWords
                          ? `${review?.review
                              .split(" ")
                              .slice(0, truncateWords)
                              .join(" ")} ...`
                          : `${review?.review}`}
                      </p>
                      <div className="flex items-center gap-2 ">
                        <h3 className="font-semibold text-yellow-100">
                          {review.rating.toFixed(1)}
                        </h3>
                        <ReactStars
                          count={5}
                          value={review.rating}
                          size={20}
                          edit={false}
                          activeColor="#ffd700"
                          emptyIcon={<FaStar />}
                          fullIcon={<FaStar />}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </SwiperSlide>
                )
              })}
              {/* <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide> */}
            </Swiper>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default ReviewSlider


I think you have add
"start":index.js(file that where all file are import)
In scripts in package.json

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
